# How to create a CGColor in an index based CGColorSpace?

Tags: core-graphics, quartz-2d, cgcolor, cgcolorspace

I'm having problems constructing a `CGColor` within an index based `CGColorSpace` using [this constructor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455927-init). `components` parameter takes 2-element array - an index of a color in the color space and alpha. The API seems to round the `CGFloat` index value to the nearest integer as well as caps it at the `last` value of the color space.

I am able to create only 2 colors from the color space table - either the first, when index is 0 or the last, when index is >= 1. How to I create any other color from the color space?

Here is sample code for reference:

```swift
let baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(
    indexedBaseSpace: baseColorSpace,
    last: 4,
    colorTable: [
        0x73, 0x1d, 0xd8,
        0x48, 0xa9, 0xa6,
        0xe4, 0xdf, 0xda,
        0xd4, 0xb4, 0x83,
        0xc1, 0x66, 0x6b
    ])!

guard let color1 = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: [2.0, 1.0]),
      let color2 = color1.converted(to: baseColorSpace, intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil) else {
    fatalError("Failed to convert color to RGB color space.")
}

print(color1.components)
print(color2.components)
```

I've tried setting index component to random values in different ranges.